# MSP432 Launchpad Board using the same pins for two different devices

Tags: c++, i2c, spi, iio, msp432

I am currently doing a Smart Metering device that uses NFC technology to communicate with a mobile phone. This device consists of 3 parts:

1. An MSP432P401R launchpad.
2. A TRF7970 (tag sensor) device connected to J1 and J2 pin arrays
3. A temperature or humidity or both sensor that I still have to buy.

I want to buy a sensor that uses I2C/SPI/UART interfaces from Texas instruments so maybe I can find some API's or at least make it easier to program, but the TRF7970 device uses all these interfaces. My question is if I can connect these devices to the same I2C/SPI/UART interfaces where the TRF7970 is connected. I know that I2C or SPI interfaces can address different slaves, but I want to be sure before buying any sensor.

Also I have some APIs which I use to communicate with the TRF7970. Would I need to change the code from those APIs?

Comment: Yes, I²C or SPI is a good choice. The problem with a former — impedance and carefully chosen pull up resistors and low speed, the problem with the later is more wires are required to connect a single device (and linearly increasing on per device basis) and incompatibility with high-noise environments (short distances of wires for high speed communication, etc). Besides above I would recommend to choose devices for which the OS has drivers for. For example, Linux kernel lists the following ones (in the latest release): https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot!! In my case there is not such a OS but a firmware as it is a microcontroller. Now that you show me those drivers I see theu are so usefull. My cuestion is, could I adapt them to my system?? For example I found some API's to control my SPI or I2C ports that could maybe suit in. Would I be able to kind of "adapt" those functions to make them work in my microcontroller??